# How to keep socket io connection alive during background? react-js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, socket.io

I have a web application in mobile that uses `socket.io` library (version 4.7.2).

**I have 2 problems with it:**

1. The main problem is that when the chrome is moved to background, the socket gets disconnected, and reconnects automatically when returning from the background.
   I need the `socket.io`-connection to stay alive while it is in the background in order to get events from the server and process them.
2. I read a lot of topics about it, but right now I have no solution. I read about `backgroundTimer` that sends ping events to server while it is in the background in `react-native`, but I'm using `react-js`.

The problem occurs mainly in Chrome browser, Android and iOS.

Socket io connection keeps alive during background.